# jQuery Tab custom event on one specific tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, dialog

I'm sure this is trivial for the more experienced. I'm trying to prevent one specified tab from looking for and opening its corresponding div. Instead, do whatever I specify, such as open a dialog.

I've tried binding to the tab then using return false and preventDefault(), which works on all tabs in general, but not the one specified when I narrow the selector, it just opens the div like a typical tab would, no errors from console.

I've also tried keeping that specific tab intentionally broken, without its div, which causes all kinds of goofy stuff... bad code anyways.

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs1">tabs 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs2">tabs 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#customtab">custom tab</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs1">
    etc
  </div>
  ..
  <div id="customtab">
    dialog content
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#tabs [href=#customtab]").bind('tabselect', function(){
  alert("do whatever I say here");
  return false;
});
```

Obviously my approach is wrong. Suggestions?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [beforeActivate](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate) event

```
$("#tabs").bind('tabsbeforeactivate', function (e, ui) {
    if (ui.newPanel.is('#customtab')) {
        console.log("do whatever I say here", ui);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vAQ7d/)

If jQuery UI 1.8

```
$("#tabs").bind('tabsselect', function (e, ui) {
    if ($(ui.panel).is('#customtab')) {
        console.log("do whatever I say here", ui);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rcRdt/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, no errors though. I'm using 1.4.4 and UI:1.8.1 .... likely cause?

Comment: ahh. works great and thank you!

Another small issue that I ran into, not related to your solution, is I had the dialog constructor also referencing #customtab. Regardless of the return false in your solution, tabs.js still returned mismatched fragment identifier, as if the corresponding div didn't exist. after looking at the element inspector it became clear that the dialog constructor made the element unavailable to tabs. anyway around this?

Comment: are you trying to display a dialog when the custom tab is clicked

Comment: yessir I am. Leaving #customtab div empty, then simply making another for the dialog works just fine... just curious if it can be done with less?

Comment: why cann't you place a simple div as a placeholder tab and user another element for the dialog

Comment: I can, no problem. Just wanted to see if it was possible without the placeholder. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @joe Also why are you using a very old version(jquery 1.4) and UI 1.8.1

Comment: Its a long story and not worth your time, rest assured that it will be updated. Thanks again, you've been a great help!

Comment: Works for me as well. Thanks a lot!